# Use selenium under ubuntu machine with no display

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not able to find a way to run selenium under ubuntu machine with no display.

I have the following java code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        String url = args[0];

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String scriptToExecute = "var network = performance.getEntries() || {}; return network;";

        driver.navigate().to(url);
        String netData = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(scriptToExecute).toString();

        System.out.println(netData);
    }
```

This code works fine on my local machine but it does not work on my ubuntu server.
This is the exception raised on "driver.navigate().to(url);":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.8.0-51-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 37 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'craw-temp', ip: '10.132.0.56', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.8.0-51-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461571 (8a88bbe0775e2a23afda0ceaf2ef7ee74e822cc5),platform=Linux 4.8.0-51-generic x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: de392db337e4adbd5876d2b8c5ca105c
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.to(RemoteWebDriver.java:902)
    at it.thirdplace.crawlertag_be.SeleniumChrome2.main(SeleniumChrome2.java:45)
    ... 5 more
```

I suppose the problem is related to the absence of the display on my ubuntu server.

This is the dependencies I installed on my ubuntu server:

- libnss3
- GConf-2.4
- libfontconfig
- google-chrome-stable

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: use Xvfb as a virtual display

Comment: Headlessly? how about `phantomjs`?